# Mod-Rewrite Pass through

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL structure that has to be passed through as following

```
www.mysite.com/path1/path2/pageA.html - www.mysite.com/pageA.html
www.mysite.com/path1/path2/path3/pageB.html - www.mysite.com/path3/pageB.html
```

So I need to hide the /path1/path2 just after the domain.

I have written the following code in configuration file

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /path1/path2/$1 [PT, L]
```

I am getting the following error with this code

```
RewriteCond: bad flag delimeters
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is because you have a space between `PT,` and `L`, and since mod_rewrite is not so smart about parsing things, it thinks those are 2 different arguments.

The other thing is you have your URI pattern start with a `/`, since apache 2, the URI's used to match rules in htaccess files have the leading slash removed, so you can't match `^/`.

The last thing is that your rule could cause a rewrite loop, since the rule's target will match the pattern in the next iteration. Mod_rewrite loops through all the rules until the URI stops changing, so you may need to add a condition to prevent this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path1/path2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path1/path2/$1 [PT,L]
```